# How to draw a CSS shape

Tags: css

is possible to draw CSS shape like (Not necessarily exact):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2):

it will be much better with SVG I think, or just using photoshop to make a `.png`

But using css for sure you can do it

```css
.the1 {
  position: fixed;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
  left: -15%;
    height:100%;
  top: 12%;
    border-top-left-radius:50%;
    border-top-right-radius:100%;
}


.the2 {
  position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
  left: 15%;
    height:100%;
  top: 12%;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
    border-top-right-radius:10%;
}

.the3 {
  position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    width:50%;
  left: 52%;
    height:32%;
  top:3%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
}

body{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">


<div class="the1">
</div>
<div class="the2"></div>
<div class="the3"></div>

</div>
```